# Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel in production but not in dev environment

Tags: c#, .net, tls1.2

I have been struggling with an SSL/TLS issue and curious if anyone has some ideas.  I am doing a web request using a pfx cert. It works fine on my dev machine but when in our production environment we get a "Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel".  If you look through similar issues on stackoverflow everyone will tell you to add some variation like:

```
System.Net.ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls11 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls;
```

To your code before the web request. I've already done this and I have used this solution in the past but it is not fixing this issue.  I used ssllabs and it does look like the server I am trying to talk to is using TLS 1.2 for what it's worth.

I've tried loading the code up on 3 different servers with 2 of them having a very simple security.  One of them is even just a cheap, shared host.  No luck, same issue.

Here is some sample code:

```
        string url = "https://api.fakedomain.com";
        string certPath = @"c:\fakefolder\mycert.pfx";
        System.Net.ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls11 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls;

        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
        var cert = new X509Certificate2(certPath);    
        request.ClientCertificates.Add(cert);  

        request.Method = "GET";
        request.ContentType = "application/json";

        using (HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse())
        {
            using (Stream stream = response.GetResponseStream())
            {
                StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream);
               string  result = reader.ReadToEnd();
           
                Response.Write("Result: " + result);
            }
        }
```

Any ideas on how I could troubleshoot this further?

What I have done:

1. Setting the TLS version explicitly
2. Loading it on various servers
3. Verify it is loading the cert

I am expecting a json string back from the request which is how it works in my dev environment.

Comment: The service point manager is supposed to be configured at the beginning of your app. Setting just before your request means that possibly there are other requests earlier which prevents the setting from being applied

Comment: It seems to be common place in a web app to set the protocol right before the request.  Additionally, one of my test servers isn't really used at all so I could guarantee on my test page that the only active request was the one I was currently executing.

Comment: The following may be helpful: [Transport Layer Security (TLS) best practices with the .NET Framework](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/network-programming/tls) and [Protocols in TLS/SSL (Schannel SSP)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/secauthn/protocols-in-tls-ssl--schannel-ssp-#tls-protocol-version-support)

Comment: using [network monitor](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/4865) to [analyze the handshake](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/iis-support-blog/troubleshooting-tls-ssl-communication-problems-when-making-http/ba-p/481296)?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code I use to set SecurityProtocol :

```
  internal static void SetServicePointmanagerSecurityProtocols() 
    { 
     try 
      {
        ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Ssl3 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls | 
                                              (SecurityProtocolType)((System.Security.Authentication.SslProtocols)0x00000300) | (SecurityProtocolType)((System.Security.Authentication.SslProtocols)0x00000C00) ; // Tls1 + Tls12
        if (Enum.IsDefined(typeof(System.Net.SecurityProtocolType),System.Net.SecurityProtocolType.Tls12))
          ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol | (SecurityProtocolType)((System.Security.Authentication.SslProtocols)0x00003000) ; // Tls13 (triggers an exception in NET35)
      } 
      catch {}
   }
```

Comment: Did this static function solve the problem and where do you call it?

Comment: @GRF: It is called once at program start. I am not sure that it will solve your problem (even if it solved mine), but it is easy to test.