# Windows 7 64bit Pro: Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel. System.Net.WebException

Tags: c#

I am running Windows 7 64 bit Pro and Trying to download images here is the ERROR msg - $exception "The request was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel."

I made a test program and installed it on a Windows 10 Machine and it doesn't happen

Any Idea How to Fix this on Windows 7 64 bit Pro with SP1 installed?

I am using Visual Studio 2017 Express. This is a Winforms application using C#.

```
            using (var client = new WebClient())
            {
                try
                {
                    ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
                    var imageBytes = client.DownloadData("https://s.turbifycdn.com/aah/yhst-86819191144034/4g-lte-all-in-one-battery-powered-smoke-detector-spy-camera-8.png");

                    MessageBox.Show("Image URL Tested OK", "Test Status");
                }
                catch(Exception ex)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Test Status"); // The request was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel
                }
            }
```

Comment: You are asking explicitly to use TLS1.2, But it isn't available on that machine. Perhaps you should remove that line.

Comment: Or look at this question on superuser: https://superuser.com/questions/1689628/how-can-one-check-whether-my-windows-7-supports-tls-1-2

Comment: Yes. It is checkmarked in Control Panel\Network and Internet - Advanced Tab. This code works on a Windows 10 PC,

Comment: In Windows 7, required cipher suites are most probably missing

Comment: _"I am running Windows 7 64 bit Pro"_ - nobody should, though.

Comment: I posted some code in that discussion: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75990284/could-not-create-ssl-tls-secure-channel-in-production-but-not-in-dev-environment

Comment: I added this entry in the registry... HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\Protocols\TLS 1.2\Client\Enabled = 1 and made sure TLS 1.2 is checked in the Control Panels Advanced tab, In my registry it shows TLS1.2 without a space between S and 1. Restarted my PC, but still get the same exception. Graffito, did you find a fix on your end?

Comment: I have Norton 360 installed. Is there some setting in that that may be causing this exception?

Comment: Windows 7 is now heavily out of date and insecure, and is not receiving any updates at all. At the very least you should follow the Microsoft instructions to switch on TLS1.2 https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/update-to-enable-tls-1-1-and-tls-1-2-as-default-secure-protocols-in-winhttp-in-windows-c4bd73d2-31d7-761e-0178-11268bb10392

Comment: I found out what is causing this but not how to fix it. The ServiceProcol is returning null for the Certificate value.
 
So in Wondows 7 I opend up the certmgr.msc and imported the certificate I exported from this link into Certificates->Trusted Root Certification Authorities.

Comment: When I added the certificate I got a Sercurity Warning dialog. It says, Windows cannot validate that the certificate is actually from turbifycdn.com. you should confirm it's origin by contacting turbifycdn.com. The following number will assist you in this process: Thumbprint (sha1): C7DC84AA 08640797 CC8C31F3 C99D0D66 391F99B2

Warning: Installing a certificate with an unconfirmed thumbprint is a security risk but reports that The certificate is valid and issued by Amazon RSA 2048 M01